# Como cambiar la posición de un EditText programáticamente.?

Tags: java, android, edittext, studio

Quería saber cómo se le puede cambiar la posición a un EditText por medio de código, me explico, tengo un layout con un Switch y debajo dos EditText, lo que intento hacer es que cuando activo el Switch desaparezca el EditText1 y pase a ocupar su posición el EditText2, y cuando se desactive el Switch vualvan a aparecer los dos EditText como al principio.

He estado buscando información al respecto pero no consigo nada en concreto, aunque en principio no debería de ser nada complicado.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch switch1, switch2;
EditText editText1, editText2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void CompruebaSwitch(View view) {

    if (switch1.isChecked ()){
        editText1.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );
        editText2.setVisibility ( View.INVISIBLE );

        // aquí es donde deberia ir el código para posicionar el editText2
        // en la posición del editText1 y vuelvo a hacer visible el editText2
        editText2.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
    }else {
        editText1.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
        editText2.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
    }
 }
}
```

Y el activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="CompruebaSwitch"
    android:text="Switch"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="EditText1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="EditText 2"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No encontré una forma como tal de "mover" un elemento de la vista, pero con el metodo que te voy a decir puede funcionar bien:

Quedaría así:

[image: Ejemplo]

Para esto, tuve que manejar un contenedor extra, es decir un LinearLayout para poder dar una orientación mejor a los elementos. Tus 3 elementos, es decir, Switch y los dos EditText los incluí en un Linear de la siguiente manera.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="CompruebaSwitch"
        android:text="Switch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="EditText 1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="EditText 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Y luego, al estar el Linear orientado de manera vertical puedes simplemente ocultar el primer EditText y el otro tomará su lugar inmediatamente.

El método `CompruebaSwitch` es el único que cambié:

```
public void CompruebaSwitch(View view) {

    if (switch1.isChecked ()){
        editText1.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
    }else {
        editText1.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
    }
}
```

Como dato adicional te quiero decir que esto funciona así por el hecho de que `View.INVISIBLE`, lo único que hace es que no podamos verlo, pero sigue ocupando espacio, en cambio con `View.GONE`, podrás ocultar completamente un elemento de la vista de modo que otro pueda ocupar su lugar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, aunque supongo que no será la mejor solución para todos las situaciones, en mi caso en concreto me va a la perfección.